# Settings.bundle is missing Root.plist and other items in iOS project;

Tags: xcode, settings.bundle, root.plist

I'm using xcode Version 4.2 (Build 4C199) with iOS 5.0.

I'm following the Apple's documentation at:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html

When I tried to add Settings.bundle, described under "Adding the Settings Bundle" section, I'm not getting all files under this bundle; Like after adding this bundle, I had only Settings.bundle at root of my project and there isn't any Root.plist and en.lproj etc;

Screenshot of my project:
[image: screenshot of project]

So after reading some other questions here, I found that I have to right click on settings bundle icon -> show in finder -> right click on finder item -> show package content; Now I can view Root.plist and other items; But my question is is there a way to view the hierarchy of Settings.bundle inside xcode project navigator?

The next query is how can I add Child plists under Settings.bundle? As right now I'm unable to expand Settings.bundle in my project navigator;

Comment: I just performed the same steps on my Lion XCode version 4.2 (Build 4D199) and I can expand the settings bundle to see the files (root.plist etc.). Probably, it's a bug in the Snow Leopard version of the XCode.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the same thing on another machine and same results; Wondering if anyone has reported the same issue to Apple;

Answer (score 0):

Open the package in Finder. Drag the files into the project file list (but make sure that you remove them from all build phases)

Comment: I did but they are not listing under Settings.bundle icon; They are appearing peer to it;

Comment: @Ans: I know. They won't from what I know. Does it really matter? You now have them in the project navigator and can edit them. They are still in `Settings.bundle` on disk.

Comment: ummmm ya somehow its good but does't looks good to do; It may be a fix, but not a solution; Like we have Settings.bundle itself at same level where its child are; Plus I'm unable to add other plists under Settings.bundle as 2nd level of settings page;

Comment: Again, the navigator is not a file browser or a file manager. What I suggested is to allow easy editing of `Settings.bundle` files. If what you want is that, than make a new folder in the navigator called `Settings` and drag (int the project navigator) the `Settings` files into that folder. Sound good?